# VBA Regex and String Handling

Tags: string, vba, excel, vbscript, alm

**Q1 .** In VBA, I am working on Web scraping and I am able to fetch the string and store into a variable. The string looks something like this:

```
x = "123434[STM]CompilationError_Lib.c23434[STM]LinkingError432122[STM]Null Pointer Exception"
```

What I want to do is, I will define an array , and store the substring into  each index of the array.

```
arr[0] = 123434[STM]CompilationError_Lib.c

arr[1] = 23434[STM]LinkingError

arr[2] = 432122[STM]Null Pointer Exception
```

Caveat: There can be any number of substrings. It is not always three.

The regex pattern I have written for this is :

```
myRegExp.Pattern = `"\d+[:].[A-Za-z]*.[A-Za-z._]*[^0-9]"`
```

But it is capturing only the first substring not all the three matches.How can I do that?

Comment: Please stick to a single question per question.

Comment: Why the  downvotes ? It is a valid,proud and self reliant question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I will answer your first question. I suggest you split the other parts into separate questions as already mentioned in comments.

```
Option Explicit
' Or add in Tools > References > VBScript Reg Exp for early binding
Public Sub testing()
    Dim x As String, arr() As String, i As Long, matches As Object
    x = "123434[STM]CompilationError_Lib.c23434[STM]LinkingError432122[STM]Null Pointer Exception"

    Static re As Object

    If re Is Nothing Then
        Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        re.Global = True 'Don't know how you will deploy shown here for demo
        re.MultiLine = True 'Don't know how you will deploy shown here for demo
    End If

    re.IgnoreCase = False
    re.Pattern = "\d+\[[a-zA-Z]{3}][^0-9]+"
    Set matches = re.Execute(x)

    ReDim arr(0 To matches.Count - 1)
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arr(i) = matches(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Output:

[image: Regex matches in array]

Comment: Hi @QHarr , Thanks for the answer.But the string will not contain the substring '[STM] 'always , it can be [ABC] or some other alphabets also.I am afraid then the regex pattern does not work in that case.But the storing seems fine .Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @QHarr for taking your time and writing answer for my question.It is working . I have accepted your answer.